# How to not trigger datepicker.valuechanged event when browsing month in date picker

Tags: vb.net, datepicker

I am using vb.net. I add a date picker as follows

```
Friend WithEvents dtpReportDate As System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker
```

The default date picker has left arrow and right arrow which allow you to browser previous month and following month. I add a handler to date picker valuechanged event:

```
AddHandler dtpReportDate.ValueChanged, AddressOf dtpReportDateChanged
```

Private Sub dtpReportDateChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

'do something here

End Sub

The problem is that whenever I click left arrow or right arrow to change month, the dptReportDateChanged is triggered. I do not want this happens. All I want is that after I find a month, I double click date to trigger the event.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi summer remove handler and then check it.

Comment: But I need to do something in handler...so it cannot be deleted

Comment: Create global bool variable first set it false as left or right arrow click make it true and check it in valuechanged is it true or false if false then allow it to move in it otherwise exit sub, make it true on date trigger.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
Private Sub DateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles DateTimePicker1.ValueChanged
  Me.Text = DateTimePicker1.Value.ToString
End Sub

Private Sub DateTimePicker1_DropDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles DateTimePicker1.DropDown
  RemoveHandler DateTimePicker1.ValueChanged, AddressOf DateTimePicker1_ValueChanged
End Sub

Private Sub DateTimePicker1_CloseUp(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DateTimePicker1.CloseUp
  AddHandler DateTimePicker1.ValueChanged, AddressOf DateTimePicker1_ValueChanged
  Call DateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(sender, EventArgs.Empty)
End Sub
```

Comment: But I do not quite understand the code, could you please explain a little bit?

Comment: @Summer When the calender is dropped down, you tell the DTP to stop firing the ValueChanged event, and when the calender is closed (usually by selecting a date), you have to tell the DTP to start firing that event again.  Since the event wasn't firing while you had the calendar dropped, you just call the ValueChanged procedure yourself "as if" the control just fired the event to get the new update.  Hope that's clear.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can just trigger off the CloseUp event instead of ValueChanged.  That worked well enough for me.

Comment: That's what I just did, although I think you can edit the date without dropping it down which this wouldn't catch.

Comment: Well, I suggest not using this. When users enter a new value into the DateTime picker by using a keyboard, it doesn't trigger CloseUp event.